# Concurrent update of an array field in Postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, concurrency

I have an array that I can update from multiple workers as follows: `UPDATE my_table SET arr = array_append(my_table.arr, element)`.

The problem pops up when two workers try to update the array at the same time. For instance, both workers see that at the moment of the update, the array is empty and try to append an element as follows: `array_append(empty_arr, element_a)` and `array_append(empty_arr, element_b)`. In the end, the final content of the array will be: `arr[element_a]` or `arr[element_b]` because one of the workers will finish updating the array earlier and its value will be overwritten with the value from the other worker. How can I ensure that both values are written in the array: `arr[element_a, element_b]`?

Comment: I think you're not telling us something here. That doesn't sound like the normal behaviour of PostgreSQL's transaction levels. You can test it yourself with two psql connections and a BEGIN ... UPDATE and holding back the COMMIT/ROLLBACK in one terminal.

Comment: Yes, if the two updates occur concurrently postgres will do the right thing. Read this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/transaction-iso.html

Comment: No, you are right. The query I use is this => `INSERT INTO conversations (id, org_id, numeric_id, tags) SELECT id, org_id, csid, array[name] as tag FROM tags_v2 WHERE id = 'foo' ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET tags = array_append(conversations.tags, 'append me');` When I test it as @RichardHuxton suggested, I do not get any problems though... So perhaps the problem is not in the SQL. I might need to look for something else. Thank you for the help, it was very helpful.